# Should marking a chat message as spam automatically ignore the user?

Tags: usability, messages, chat, user-expectation

Two typical features of chat rooms are, the ability to ignore another user (hide all of their messages) and to mark a particular message as spam.

Should marking a user's message as spam automatically ignore that user, or should ignoring the source of the spam have to be done explicitly by the user?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Scenario**: Your friend's messenger has 'virus' and is sending messages to his contacts. You mark his virus's message as spam.

- Do you want this to also block your friend?
- Or, do you just want to mark his message as spam?

You see, there are times when you just want to mark a message as spam since it is coming from a known contact.

**Ignoring an user should be an explicit command** since once you do that, you have to consciously check your ignore list to see who all are in there. *If your marking a message as spam also ignores the user, there should be an alert before that action is implemented.*

Comment: A pattern I've seen is, upon marking something as spam, being asked "do you want to ignore this user?".  So your system can *ask*, but you shouldn't take actions unilaterally on the user's behalf, for the reasons given in this answer.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Yes that is a good UX pattern that you brought up :)

Answer (score 6):

Marking a message as spam and blocking a have **different use cases**.

Spam is generic content that is sent to many people (usually advertising).  The goal of marking something as spam is to let your system **intelligently remove other identical (or similar) posts** so that other members don't have to be presented with this.  Gmail does an excellent job of this.

**Blocking a user is about not wanting content from them anymore**.  Think of an ex-girlfriend or boyfriend who is constantly sending you messages, or a stalker.  Blocking them prevents *you* from having to hear from them, but has no effect for the rest of the user base.

So, marking a message as spam, shouldn't automatically block a user.  If someone wants to block all contact, they can block the user, but there are many cases where you may want to mark a message as spam, but still receive contact from the user.